# Update only application name in apple story w/o new binary file upload

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, itunes-store, itunes-app

I already have the released application in Apple Story. I want only to change the application name in the Apple Story (I don't need the new binary upload).

Have I to make the new application version and to wait additional two weeks for Apple Review? What is the most quick way to change application name in Apple Story for released application?

Comment: Apple Story roll roll roll )))

Comment: you **cannot** do it, you should upload a new version of the application with the new name and you have to wait for the review process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that. Make another application upload with proper name, and reject the already approved app. And think twice before naming the app, you cannot play with this too much.